# regex space in lookahead literal

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match SQL query select fields using regex. I know that SQL syntax is really complicated and it's not good idea to do it this way but I need such a solution to fix bug.

This is what I currently have:

`/SELECT(((?!FROM).)*)FROM/is`

But to prevent from matching column like `letter_from` i need to lookahead for spaces before and after keyword `FROM`

I have tried putting spaces but it does not work as expected.

So how can I add lookahead for whitespace or at least spaces around my keyword.

Comment: `/SELECT(.+?)\bFROM\b/` - how about this?

Comment: So you want everything between `SELECT` and `FROM`?

Comment: I do not see why this is downvoted. The OP has provided: 1)  the situation he/she is in 2) the attempted solution 3) the problem/obstacle that's getting in his/her way. Therefore I shall give it a +1. We should encourage such posts.